# seqdirectory throws error in MapReduce mode when using Mahout 1.0-SNAPSHOT with Hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: java, machine-learning, mahout, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to run the seqdirectory command in Mahout 1.0-SNAPSHOT with Hadoop 2.2.0. On using the command:

```
seqdirectory -i input -o output
```

Stack trace:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(CombineFileRecordReader.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(CombineFileRecordReader.java:126)
    at org.apache.mahout.text.MultipleTextFileInputFormat.createRecordReader(MultipleTextFileInputFormat.java:43)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:734)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(CombineFileRecordReader.java:155)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.mahout.text.WholeFileRecordReader.<init>(WholeFileRecordReader.java:59)
    ... 15 more
```

I thought this was a problem in Mahout 0.9 and was fixed in the trunk. Any clues how to deal with this? I want to run it in MapReduce mode, so, -xm sequential isn't the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected`

Errors like this always mean you're running something against a version of something that's different from the one it was compiled against. Here, you didn't compile Mahout for Hadoop 2. It does not by nature work with Hadoop 2 without some build changes.

Comment: I see. Is there a maven repo which contains YARN compiled Mahout artifacts? Or, is it expected that users would have to compile Mahout locally?

Comment: No, although Hadoop distros based on Hadoop 2 that include Mahout will have modified it to make it basically work

Comment: CDH5.0 seems to be packaging Mahout 0.8. Any idea if it contains the fix for YARN back ported into Mahout 0.8?

Comment: What fix for YARN do you mean?

Comment: I mean, does the Mahout 0.8 packaging in CDH5 support using the parallel implementation for seqdirectory with YARN?

Comment: It would contain 0.8 plus a few critical fixes maybe; I don't know what that particular one is, but it is not the source of the error in your question. The problem is being compiled for Hadoop 1.